# Escape strings in Maven map

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm using a Mojo that has a `Map<String, String>` as a setting. According to

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Maps

that should be configured like:

```
<theMap>
<key1>value1</key1>
</theMap>
```

but my properties are namespace -> package mappings for xsd code generation. So that would be:

```
<packageNames>
  <http://mydomain/myservice>my.service.package.name</http://mydomain/myservice>
</packageNames>
```

which isn't even valid xml. So is there any way to escape the values or another way to map settings to a Mojo's map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of mapping [list](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Lists) and [complex objects](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Object).

In your case configuration would look like:

```
<packageNames>
  <packageName>
    <uri>http://mydomain/myservice</uri>
    <package>my.service.package.name<package>
  <packageName>
</packageNames>
```

Once you collect the List, validate that all `uris` are unique, by possibly assigning it to Map internally.  Also, document mojo, that it expects unique `uris`.